# Repeatedly show dynamic dropdowns

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to repeatedly show drop downs in a table in order to take its value and update specific records.

I have able to make dynamic dropdown using this

```
function getEmployeeTaskStatusMain(){
   var go_path = "Employee_Switch_Person.php?action=getEmployeeTaskStatusMain&vars=0";
    $jq.get(go_path,
        {
        }, function(data)
        {
            if(JSON.parse(data).length == 0){
                console.log(data);
                return data;
            }
            else {
                var dataToAppend;
                dataToAppend = "<select name='EmployeeTaskStatus' class='EmployeeTaskStatus form-control'>"
                dataToAppend += "<option value='0'>Select Status</option>";


                //console.log(" " + data);
                dataParse = JSON.parse(data);

                for (var i = 0; i < dataParse.length; i++)
                {
                    //console.log(dataParse[i]);
                    dataToAppend += "<option value=" + dataParse[i].TaskStatusMainId + ">" + dataParse[i].TaskStatusMain + "</option>";

                }

                dataToAppend +="</select>";
                $jq(".taskStatusMain").html(dataToAppend);
                //getEmployeeTaskStatusDetail(0);
                return dataParse;
            }
        });
}
```

**But do i need to repeat the above function for every table row in order to show the dropdown in each row with dynamic id(so that i can get it selected value)?**

The table (is also making dynamically) where i have to show dropdown with each record and i want to take each dropdown selected value in order to update specfic record. what is the handy way?

Remember, There are two drop downs one dropwdown value updating on another dropdown value selection.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you return this data in the users array and render it in the HTML file inside the for loop for each user and loop through his status to render the drop down?
And then update that row using the on change event for the select tag

```
<tr>
   <th>status></th>
</tr>
foreach($users as $user){
  <tr>
   <td>
     <select>
       foreach($user->status as $status-item){
         <option>$status-item->name</option>
       }
     </select>
   </td>
  </tr>
}
```

Comment: how to do this.

Comment: The same way you render each user row. You will add a column for each user containing his status do down and you loop through each user status and render them as select tag options.

Comment: Sorry I'm answering this using my phone. I'll try to type the code in a moment

Comment: ok but anyone can down vote your comments which you have actually placed in answer section. This is not correct way

Comment: That's because I couldn't comment your question and I just wanted to help

Comment: you need to add the status to each user before you send the users array from the backend